# What is the precise meaning of an "Ethernet Drop"

Tags: ethernet, cable

Do the words  "Ethernet Drop" (without other qualifications) imply that both sides of the connection are terminated in RJ45 sockets?

I am trying to interpret a document where I am unsure that work order has been met - and my subsequent actions depend on whether the contractor has performed their duty (ie do I get them to come back, or do I "finish off the job").

Comment: `I am trying to interpret a document where I am unsure that work order has been met` - Why don't you share the details of the work order so that we can answer? Redact any info that needs to be redacted. The terms "Ethernet Drop" or "Network Drop" are colloquial terms and are not officially recognized technical terms as far as I'm aware, so without knowing how the term was used and in what context, we can't tell you what the contractor did or did not do.

Comment: Additionally, the connector you're referring to is an 8P8C connector, not an RJ45 connector. Have a read here - https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/rj45-connectors